# using H2O flow XGboost model

Tags: xgboost, h2o

It gives a regression prediction as continuous score with negative values, like -1.27544 < x < 6.68112. How I interpret the negatives?

Comment: hi lana! can you provide a bit more details: why are you suprised to see negative values? what were you expecting to see? what type of problem are you trying to solve (do you want to solve a regression problem)? what does your target look like (does your target, i.e. what you are trying to predict) have negative values. Are you looking a prediction values?

Comment: My target variable is binary 0 or 1. I am trying to use xgboost to predict it It gives me the output predictions as -1.27544 < x < 6.68112 range numbers.  If it predicts a score of getting Yes/No, I would assume the score should be from 0 to 1, but it is continuous numbers with negative values.I am trying to understand what exactly your H2o xgboost predicts this way ? What the numbers mean? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an H2O algorithm to predict a binary target (0/1), unless you convert your target column to a factor using (.asfactor() in python or as.factor() in R), H2O will assume this column is numeric and will solve a regression problem.

please verify the data type of your target column (it will likely show integer) and make sure that it shows enum.

more informations about your target distribution choices can be found here: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/distribution.html

Comment: Great, thank you for your help! May I also ask you about the interpretation of the GBM prediction  outcome, which looks like a matrix of LLLRL, LLLLL, RRLLL, etc.? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi Lana, glad to be of help! Could you  mark this question as correct if it was what you were looking for. For gbm predictions please checkout previously posted questions on this topic and checkout the user guide here: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/gbm.html#leaf-node-assignment

Comment: I actually converted my target [1,0] to categorical and run xGboost - it still does regression and gives me prediction as continuous numbers with negatives. How to make H2O xgboost predict binary? Thank you!

Comment: hi lana, please set the distribution parameter to bernoulli. it would also be helpful if you could post a screen shot of what you are selecting in Flow and what Flow says the datas type of your target it. thanks!

Comment: Thanks, Lauren! I assume that the AUTO option should recognize the binary target..Unfortunately, I cannot check because H2o flow does not load the page today.  I will try that when H2O will allow me. May be you can give a tip how to load the page? I do the same I did  before, run java -jar h2o.jar. Shell give me the web link, but link does not work. I would appreciate your help. Thanks, Lana

Comment: I actually, just tried to run the Xgboost with binary categorical target variable [0 or 1] and tried to choose Bernoulli distribution, but it does not allow to choose Bernoulli, giving me a message that "binomial requires the response to be a 2-class categorical". Could you please help?

Comment: please review the answer to your original question. it is the same answer the question you are asking now.

Comment: I learned that in order to make Bernoulli working on binary solution I need to convert my, already converted in python Target column, the second time in H2O by choosing "Enum" in drop-down menu. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Lauren, I am coming back to the Bernoulli issue. I used it and it has been fine. It predicted binary outcome. I try to use it again with the same dataset, same setup, etc. BUT H2O Flow tells me that: "Binomial required the response to be a 2-class categorical". It does not make sense. If I would change something - I could miss something, but I use absolutely the same setup, same dataset with target as categorical, set it as usual to Enum(2). Could you please help?

Comment: I just checked that H2oFlow GBM accepts my target var as binary, but XGboost stopped doing that! It does not allow to use both Bernoulli or Quasibinomial distributions. But before it worked. Is something changed in H2O setup? Could somebody help, please?